# Constant Font Size In `display-line-numbers-mode` When Zooming In And Out

Tags: line-numbers, zooming

## SOLVED

The `atom-one-dark` theme that I was using was the issue.

```el
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/atom-one-dark")
(load-theme 'atom-one-dark t)
```

---

### My `init.el`:

```el
(menu-bar-mode -1)
(scroll-bar-mode -1)
(tool-bar-mode -1)

(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'display-line-numbers-mode)

(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/atom-one-dark")
(load-theme 'atom-one-dark t)

(custom-set-faces
 '(mode-line ((t (:box (:line-width 8 :color "#21252B")))))
 '(mode-line-inactive ((t (:box (:line-width 8 :color "#181A1F"))))))
```

I am new to Emacs, I've set up `display-line-numbers-mode` like so:

```el
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'display-line-numbers-mode)
```

This enables `display-line-numbers-mode` on all source code files (ex: .py, .js), and it works fine.

[image: display-line-numbers-mode works perfectly]

Now, my problem is that the font size is always constant, meaning that when I zoom in, this happens:

[image: When I zoom in]

And when I zoom out:

[image: When I zoom out]

### **Doom Emacs**

Surprisingly enough, Doom Emacs uses `display-line-numbers-mode`, and has managed to fix this issue, I don't know how they did it:

Normal:
[image: Doom Emacs Normal]

Zoom Out:

[image: Doom Emacs Zoom Out]

Zoom In:

[image: Doom Emacs Zoom In]

I don't exactly know how they managed to fix it, I found some of their code [here](https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs/blob/master/lisp/doom-ui.el#L479)

### **Why Did I Ask?**

I am having this issue, and I didn't found anything regarding this issue on the Internet. Google (Startpage) is giving me irrelevant results, ex. `linum-mode`

### **How You Can Answer This Question**

**Do's**:

- Correct any misinformation (comment), example: *Doom Emacs doesn't use `display-line-numbers-mode`*
- Solve my issue (answer), please write `elisp` code blocks in the answer since I am new.
- Refer to websites or answers that you think is helpful (comment or answer).
- Show me how you did it in your config (answer)

**Dont's**:

- Don't refer to `linum-mode`, I've already tried it, and it has many issues. + Doom Emacs did it right, despite them using `display-line-numbers-mode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **SOLVED**

I was using a theme called `atom-one-dark`:

```el
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/atom-one-dark-theme")
(load-theme 'atom-one-dark t)
```

The theme source code contained these two *faulty* lines:

```el
`(line-number ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-gutter :background ,atom-one-dark-bg))))
`(line-number-current-line ((t (:foreground ,atom-one-dark-fg :background ,atom-one-dark-bg))))
```

This is not only for `atom-one-dark`, but for many other themes that I've tried like `catppuccin`. I've **commented** the two lines and my problem is solved. But the line number colors reverted to the default grayish color, which I didn't like.

I wanted to change the color of the line numbers, I tried, and changed it to `cyan`, and it worked. But my problem is back again, the line numbers don't look right when I zoom in & out. When I reverted back to the normal foreground color for the line numbers, it worked and the issue was resolved. But I still wanted some *bling* to my line numbers.

I fired up Doom Emacs, and began to browse in the Customization Browser (`M-x customize-browse`), and began to look for the `line-number` face. This is what I found.

[image: Doom Emacs]

I fired up my own GNU Emacs and copied all the options, it worked perfectly even when I change the foreground color, the font, or the font style. I began to analyse the options, to know which one solved my problem, and it was the `Inherit` option. It was set to `default`, which is the default face which can be looked up in the Customization Browser in `Faces > Basic Faces > Default`.

I set the `inherit` option in my `line-number` face (`Environment > Display > Display Line Numbers > Line Number`) to `default` (The Default face) and everything worked, no matter how I customized the other options.

### **TL;DR**

Set the `inherit` option to `default`. (This is how Doom Emacs does it)

Answer (score 0):

What Emacs release are you using?

Do you see this when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file). If so, bisect your init file to find the culprit. If not, provide a step-by-step recipe starting from `emacs -Q` to repro the problem.

I don't see what you describe - I see the line numbers zoom along with the text.

But you don't say how you are zooming. Are you using `C-x C-=` etc. (`text-scale-adjust`)? If not, try that.

---

Note that if you are using an Emacs 29 dev build, there is an outstanding bug with `global-text-scale-adjust`: [Bug #59122](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=59122).

Comment: Well actually, you are right, when running `emacs -Q`, it works seamlessly. My config is only in `init.el`, which is the file displayed in the images. And yes, I use `C-x C-=`

Comment: Bisect your init file, to see where/how you are shooting yourself in the foot, then don't do that. ;-)

Comment: Actually, the problem is when I set a foreground face to Display Line Numbers, for example: `(custom-set-faces '(line-number ((t (:foreground "cyan")))))`, why is that happening? (Emacs Version 28.2)